# Is D backwards compatible with C if you use the C libraries?

Tags: c, d, backwards-compatibility, phobos

If I import the std.c libaries instead of including the libraries in C, would C code compile with a D compiler, or are there other backwords compatibility issues?

Comment: Definitely maybe.  :-)  Per the [D overview page](http://dlang.org/overview.html) "10. Where D code looks the same as C code, have it either behave the same or issue an error.
").  So it's possible that SOME C code will compile and run fine under D, but I don't think you can say that ALL C code will compile and run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several subtleties in D that can make C code not behave exactly as you may want it to. For instance, integer promotion rules are not quite the same (but almost), and initialization rules are different (floating point values -- including arrays of such -- are initialized to NaN, for example). Further, C function pointer syntax was deprecated recently, so you might have to translate some C type syntax to the equivalent D syntax.

In general, though, there is great focus on backwards compatibility, and *most* C code should compile fine (or with a very minor amount of changes) in D with the same semantics as in C.

Also note that `std.c` is deprecated; please use `core.stdc` instead.

Comment: Of course, all the preprocessor hacks in your C code will have to be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is different from the one you ask in the OP body.

Q1: *Is D backwards compatible with C if you use the C libraries?*

A: Yes. You can use C libraries. More about this [here](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html).

Q2: *Would C code compile with a D compiler?*

A: It was never intention for an implementation of D compiler to be able to compile C code. However, lots of C code would compile because D *[matches C compiler's data types, layouts, and function call/return sequences](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html)*. As Zor pointed out [C-style function pointer syntax](http://dlang.org/deprecate#C-style%20function%20pointers), and [C-style array pointer syntax](http://dlang.org/deprecate#C-style%20array%20pointers) has been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You're never going to be able to take a C or C++ file and compile at as D code, and you can't just `#include` C headers in D. D is *not* backwards compatible with either C or C++. Rather, it's possible to declare `extern(C)` functions in your D code and call those C functions as if they were D functions (naturally, you then have to link with the C library that they're defined in). See

- [Interfacing to C](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html)
- [Interfacing to C++](http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html)
- [Converting C.h Files to D Modules](http://dlang.org/htomodule.html)

for details on calling C code from D.

druntime (which contains the core.* modules) has declarations for quite a few of the standard C and OS functions (in the core.stdc.* and core.sys.* modules), but you'll have to look at the druntime files yourself to see what they are, because they're not properly documented at this point. For any other C functions that you want to call, you can easily create declarations for them yourself, as described in the links above.

Now, C and D are very similar syntactically, so some sections of C code will compile just fine as D code, but programs as a whole will not. The general rule is that C/C++ code will either compile as valid D code with the same semantics, or it won't compile as D code. There are a few cases where that isn't true (e.g. static arrays are value types in D, unlike C/C++), but it is in almost all cases. This makes *porting* C/C++ code to D fairly easy, but it was never intended that D be backwards compatible with C code in the way that C++ is.